# Detecting if a file is a video in Python?

Tags: python, video, file-upload, mime-types

Is there any Python library that I can use to detect if a file is a video?  I am letting users upload videos to my site and I want to prevent images and documents and anything except video filetypes.  I my plan right now it to upload any file, test it, if it isn't a video delete it, if it is process it through the normal pipeline.  I'd love to test for corrupt video somehow but that is another matter.

I need to be able to support videos without extensions.  I had thought the mimetypes library could do this but when I do the following:

```
import mimetypes

url = 'http://thehighlightnetwork.appspot.com/serve/AMIfv94NsD5mUOwE60RnMSsBKVUsgilNyNJZawl30CRqVnLad7HkNeMmdBQCMhiAOXc0N9onNGjAM19TTVENEPjAwpeQZ6dq25CWjD5DzQXoK0c4IaPum_L-83EQS4SeUNqOCEYleHTskfkhfC8BXZJQtlyA99g2nN9lrfCXWrNGYPtjDeZETEQ'
print mimetypes.guess_type(url)
```

I get:

```
(None, None)
```

I am using Google App Engine so I have all the built in libraries but can add nearly anything too.

Comment: https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic ... but it looks like you will need to manually install some DLL's (unless you are on *nix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `python-magic`, OS-independent

```
pip install python-magic
```

**Dependencies for Windows and OSX**

On Windows, you need to download and save the following libraries under C:\Windows\System32:

```
regex2.dll from sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/regex/
zlib1.dll from sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/zlib/
magic1.dll from sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/file/
```

On OSX:

```
When using Homebrew: brew install file-formula
When using macports: port install file
```

Then execute the code in python:

```
import magic
magic.from_file("path/to/file/filename.extension")

# usage example
magic.from_file("test/test.avi", mime=True)
```

For any further details refer [Python-Magic](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic)

Output when i ran:

```
>>> import magic

>>> magic.from_file("test.avi")
'RIFF (little-endian) data, AVI, 320 x 240, 25.00 fps, video: XviD, audio: MPEG-1 Layer 3 (stereo, 22050 Hz)'
```

Answer (score 1):

On UNIX systems, there exists a program for identifying files. It is called `file` and matches patterns from a plain-text database.

If google app-engine gives you access to libmagic (which I doubt but I'm not familiar with it), you can install [python-magic](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-magic/) to use that.

Otherwise, probably the best way is to download the signature database. You can find e.g. the one used by FreeBSD [for videos](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/stable/9/contrib/file/Magdir/animation?view=co) online. The documentation of tha file's format is [also online](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=magic&apropos=0&sektion=5&manpath=FreeBSD%209.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html).

Using these signature you should be able to detect the type of a file by reading the start of the file and matching it with the signatures.